# Animated display button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to create a basic animation. I need to touch on a button to hide or show.

I wrote this code to tap on the screen:

```
func visibleControlButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if (backButton!.isHidden) {
        _UIButtonHiddenAnimation.hiddenAnimation(button: self.backButton!, hide: false)
    } else {
        _UIButtonHiddenAnimation.hiddenAnimation(button: self.backButton!, hide: true)
    }
}
```

Definition _UIButtonHiddenAnimation:

```
 class _UIButtonHiddenAnimation {
    class func hiddenAnimation(button: UIButton, hide: Bool) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2,
                       animations: {
                            hide ? (button.alpha = 0) : (button.alpha = 1.0)
                        },
                       completion: {
                            finished in hide ? (button.isHidden = true) : (button.isHidden = false)
                        })
    }
}
```

Animates just hide the button. How to make an animated appearance of a button?

Comment: the code u wrote should hide and show just fine. the problem is after the button gets hidden, you cannot tap on the same button. So you shouldnt write the `self.isHidden` code in the completion block, and you are good to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if the button is hidden, you are animating the alpha to 1 but we cannot see that — because the button is hidden! Then you set `isHidden` to `false` and the button jumps into view.

The solution: forget all about `isHidden` and change only the alpha — and then change your `if` test to match what you are doing with the button, i.e. simply test against its `alpha` value. Thus (neatening things up as we go):

```
class _UIButtonHiddenAnimation {
    class func hiddenAnimation(button: UIButton, hide: Bool) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            button.alpha = hide ? 0 : 1.0
        })
    }
}

func visibleControlButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    _UIButtonHiddenAnimation.hiddenAnimation(
        button: self.backButton!, hide: backButton!.alpha > 0.1)
}
```